# definition of a graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, definite-integrals

I have two questions;

> 1. What is the **name of the graph** (or circuit) which goes along the **outer vertices of     existing nodes**.
> 2. What will be the **formal definition** of that graph.

for the simplicity, I have added a sample figure and the red highlighted graph is what I wanted.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem well defined, unless we're specifically talking about graphs drawn in the plane.

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily uniquely defined: consider what would happen if you removed one of the black edges - then you could put the black node either inside or outside.

Answer (score 2):

If your graph is a *plane graph* (that is, a particular embedding of a planar graph) then what you're looking for is the "boundary of the outer face".

A face is defined as you would expect much like polyhedral faces, as an area contained by a cycle that has no edges crossing it.

The outer face is then the face with unbounded area. Or you can think of the outer boundary as the cycle which has the rest of the graph "inside" (you have to define inside and outside for this of course).

There is an imprecision here as we haven't dealt with trees incident to the outer face, but it's easy enough to see how to deal with such a case.

Comment: A face in a planar embedding is a subset of the plane. The red cycle is the boundary of the outer face.

Comment: @Luke Mathieson: not sure that i got your suggestion. Then how could i define this. i didnot get this face case. for that, do i need to use graph concepts or something else?

Comment: @Chris Godsil: sorry, did not get. how do i define this in a formal way interms of faces. does faces coming under graph theory or another branch of mathematics?

Comment: @ChrisGodsil, quite right. Adjustments made.

Comment: @g_niro, the idea of having an "outer" part puts you into some sort of space, so we do require more than (simple) graph theoretic concepts. You can generalise to higher dimensions, but 2D is easiest to think of. You need a plane into which the graph is embedded, vertices map to points, edges to curves between the  points. Then a cycle in the graph defines a region of the plane, if this region is not crossed by any edge, then it is a face. The outer face is the unbounded one, the red cycle in your drawing is its boundary.

Comment: @ Luke Mathieson: ok thanks. if i have a hanging edge from one of the red nodes, then do you think it is crossing.

Comment: @g_into, no, it doesn't divide the face into two bits, so it doesn't "cross" the face.

Comment: @Luke Mathieson: If I say, In terms of topology, can't I define something like outer vertices and then bring into graph theories?

Comment: @g_into, yeah once you start talking about ideas like inside and outside, the you're talking topology one way or another - faces are defined by connectivity, and hence are in a sense topological.

Answer (score 0):

This question only makes sense if you are talking about a planar graph.

The face you are talking about is indeed the "outer face" (as Luke says).  However, there are two problems that arise if you try to formalize this idea:

- You can turn ANY face of the planar graph into an outer face just by redrawing the graph.  To see this, imagine drawing the graph on a sphere.  The sphere is the same as the plane, except now the "outer" face and all the other faces are indistinguishable.  (If you want, you can use the [Riemann sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere) to map the graph from the plane to the sphere, then rotate the sphere to have a different face on top, and then map the graph back from the sphere to the plane again.  This changes any face to the outer face in your drawing.)
- Depending on how you draw the graph, you may get a different set of faces.
  For instance, consider an octagon (8-cycle) on the vertices $A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H$, with $A$ connected to $B$, $B$ to $C$, and so on, ending with $H$ connecting to $A$. Now connect $A$ to $D$ and $E$ to $H$.
  Note that the 6-cycle $A,B,C,D,E,H$ may or may not be a face, depending on how you draw the graph.  (Try to draw it in two different ways and see for yourself.)

So the short answer to your question is, this is not a useful or a well-defined property of a graph, at least the way you seem to be stating it here.  Unless you just fix the graph in $\mathbb{R}^2$, that is, in which case you are hardly talking about a graph at all.